# Converting a `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` object to `datetime`

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` object to `datetime`.`df['orig_iss_dt']` is the `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` object. I used the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852044/converting-pandas-tslib-timestamp-to-datetime-python) to try and do this, but find that `print(type(origination))` still returns the same type.

```
df['orig_iss_dt'] = df['orig_iss_dt'].apply(lambda x: datetime.date(x.year,x.month,x.day)) 

for (i, row) in df:
    origination = row.orig_iss_dt
    print(type(origination))
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to convert a pandas `Timestamp` to `datetime.datetime` is to use the `to_pydatetime` method. This can be called on `Timestamp` directly or on the series:

```
In [15]: s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=3))

In [16]: s
Out[16]:
0   2012-01-01
1   2012-01-02
2   2012-01-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [17]: s[0]
Out[17]: Timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00')

In [18]: s.dt.to_pydatetime()
Out[18]:
array([datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 3, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

But note that this is often times not needed, as `Timestamp` is a subclass of `datetime.datetime`.