# Converting pandas.tslib.Timestamp with tzinfo to datetime python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I ask question right after trying: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852044/converting-pandas-tslib-timestamp-to-datetime-python).

Have dates:

```
type(md):
pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp
```

But it look different from the

`Timestamp('2016-03-03 00:00:00')`,

namely:

`Timestamp('2018-02-02 23:59:59+0000', tz='UTC')`

So,  how can i just ignore `tzinfo` and convert it to a `datetime.datetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the time-zone info, i.e., set it to default which is `None`, and then convert it to Python's `datetime` object as follows:

```
ts = pd.Timestamp('2018-02-02 23:59:59+0000', tz='UTC')

ts.tz_convert(None)
# returns Timestamp('2018-02-02 23:59:59')

ts.tz_convert(None).to_pydatetime()
# returns datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 2, 23, 59, 59)
```